# JavaScript : Inherit constructor properties from Parent Class

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Lets assume  i have a baseclass and i want to inherit the properties from the constructor.

---

*Note: This is an example code. It is not intended to work or anything, just to demonstrate my problem*

**Base Class**

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    /* SOME CLASS METHODS */ }
```

**Myclass**

```
class Myclass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    };

/* SOME CLASS METHODS */ }
```

---

**MyProblem**

> let test = Myclass('dog', 'cat');

However, this doesnt seem to work. Why does the Myclass-constructor not initialize the BaseClass constructor? When i look at the debugger for *this.a* and *this.b*, this values are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor() {
    super();
};
```

Your child class is overriding the constructor, is not accepting any arguments, and passes no arguments to the parent constructor (`super()`), so all parameters in the parent constructor are `undefined`. Your child constructor needs to accept the same or more parameters, and/or provide default arguments to `super()`.

In this particular case, the child constructor doesn't do anything, so may as well be omitted entirely.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass through an a and b value to the super method

like here:

```
class Myclass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(a, b) {
        super(a, b);
};
```

[super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)